# Error in running overflow dag returned a failure:{error_message}\n{remote_pod}

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I am a newbie to airflow. When I tried to run my task, I got this error. Can someone help me? Thanks

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 422, in execute
    remote_pod=remote_pod,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 445, in cleanup
    f'Pod {pod and pod.metadata.name} returned a failure:{error_message}\n{remote_pod}'
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod run-dbt-494b8379c6424a40ad3d14b05f2c4e2c returned a failure:
None
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually `f'Pod {pod and pod.metadata.name} returned a failure:{error_message}\n{remote_pod}'` is from airflow source code, it's in the exception Traceback, but the error message is `Pod run-dbt-494b8379c6424a40ad3d14b05f2c4e2c returned a failure: None`, so the pod fails without an error message, can you execute `kubectl describe pod <pod id>` just after getting this error? and maybe `kubectl logs <pod if>`